# how to seperate 2 callbacks from an ajax request in 2 different divs

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How can I separate a callback from ajax request into 2 different divs?

This is the php code:

```
if( isset($_POST['writedir']) ){
  // some code goes here
  echo "this is echo 1";
  echo "this is echo 2";
}
```

And the ajax:

```
$.ajax({
url: "",
type: "post",
data:  new FormData(this),
cache: false,               
contentType: false,
processData: false,             
beforeSend: function () {
     window.location.hash='close'; /* disappear upload modal */
    },
success: function(data) {   

    $('.echo-one').html(data); // here should come content echo 1
    $('.echo-two').html(data); // here should come content echo 2       


},

});
```

So the first echo should come in div with class `.echo-one` and the second in div with class `echo-two`

Comment: Look into a structured response from your PHP script, something like a JSON response which can be an array or an object with multiple members. Each member can be passed to a different target in your success handler function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Structure your data.

Create an array of your values:

```
$result = [
    "one" => "this is echo 1",
    "two" => "this is echo 2"
];
```

Then echo is to the output as JSON:

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

What should be returned to your JavaScript code should then be:

```
{ "one" : "this is echo 1", "two" : "this is echo 2" }
```

Then you can place the data elements where you want them:

```
$('.echo-one').html(data.one);
$('.echo-two').html(data.two);
```

Comment: WAY faster than I was!